# Auto-login with cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I've been trying to make an auto-login feature for my login script for 2 nights now.

I have a field in my users table called `session_key` varchar(255) in which I store the users IP address hashed with MD5.

If the cookie is set, session variables will be set and if not a form will appear.

When they login and if they have checked a checkbox named `autologin` it will store their MD5 hashed IP address in field `session_key`.

Now if they close their browser and come back, I check that their cookie is equal to session_key in the database.

This is the messy code! I didn't think it would be this hard to implement an auto-login function...

```
session_start();

// see if the auto-login cookie exists, if so set sessions vars
if (isset($_COOKIE['autologin'])) {
$user=mysql_query("select * from users where session_key = $_COOKIE[autologin]");
$row3=mysql_fetch_assoc($user);



        if ($_COOKIE['autologin'] == $row3['session_key']) {

           $_SESSION['id'] = $row3['id'];
           header("Location: login.php");
        }
    }


// User pressed "Login"
if (count($_POST)) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users 
                       WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' 
                       AND password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."' ");


if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        $error = '<script>alert("Wrong username and/or password.\nTry again.")    </script>';
} else {
    $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'id');
    header("Location: login.php");
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET session_key = '".md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."'");
    setcookie("autologin", md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), time()+3600);
}

}



if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

exit('You are logged in!');

}



<form method="post">

<tr>
<td valign="top" width="95px"><b>Username:</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="username" size="22" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top"><b>Password:</b></td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" size="22" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top"><b>Auto-login:</b></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="autologin" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
</tr>

</form>
```

Is this even safe? Is it easy to manipulate cookies?

Afaik, youtube sports this function - how do they do it?

I can't get this to work, can someone help me?

Comment: You forgot to mention what the problem is that you are trying to solve. You say that you can't get it to work - this implies that it actually doesn't work. If so, what is the specific error that you get?

Answer (score 3):

First, don't ever stick strings from your user (this includes cookies) into your SQL without escaping it first.

Secondly, session keys need to be unique, and hard to guess. It looks like all I have to do to steal someone's session is to know their IP address. Worse yet, I can steal their session by accident by having the same IP as them (which is very often the case if I'm in the same building they are).

Third, your indentation doesn't match your curly brackets, so it's hard to figure out what's going on.

Fourth, this `"if ($_COOKIE['autologin'] == $row3['session_key'])"` is redundant, since you already checked in SQL that they match.

Fifth, on your 5th line, you don't have quote marks around your (unescaped) value, so if your code execution had ever gotten to this point, you should get an SQL syntax error.

I suggest you make much much simpler smaller pieces of code that you test one at a time. For example, start with setting a cookie, and testing that the value comes through. Then only after you get that working, add some code to check if a database record matches your cookie. And make sure to encode everything you put in sql, so if someone sets their cookie to "; drop database xxx" or whatever, you aren't screwed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

```
    // User pressed "Login"
if (count($_POST)) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users 
                       WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' 
                       AND password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."' ");


if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            $error = '<script>alert("Wrong username and/or password.\nTry again.")    </script>';
} else {
    $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'id');
        header("Location: login.php");
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET session_key = '".md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."'");
        setcookie("autologin", md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), time()+3600);
}

}
```

In the last section where you have written:

```
header("Location: login.php");
```

You are updating database and setting cookie, after you are redirecting the user by header function. So your code never updates and set that cookie. 
Change it to:

```
 // User pressed "Login"
if (count($_POST)) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users 
                       WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' 
                       AND password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."' ");


if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            $error = '<script>alert("Wrong username and/or password.\nTry again.")    </script>';
} else {
    $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'id');
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET session_key = '".md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."'");
        setcookie("autologin", md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), time()+3600);
        header("Location: login.php");

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the whole schema involving IP addresses won't cut it. You have to account for people on portable devices (most of the world), and people with dynamic IP addresses (most of the rest) which can and do change at any time.

You might try UID session cookies and save only the session ID in the browser cookies while maintaining the connected state in the user database record.

To integrate device dependence, the browser string from the request header is often used, and saved in the user record.

This is also an easy way to force everyone to login after system changes (ie TOS).

### Might be a good opportunity to practice connection-state diagrams.

Sorry, any code I might include would be language and integration specific but I also use check digits in my USER-IDs so I can validate them without DB usage. (A topic for another discussion)